# Upgrading log4j 1.2.14 to 2.12.1 Error No Root logger was configured and No log file created

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are upgrading log4j `1.2.14` to `2.12.1` and I have the `log4j2.properties` file as below

```
status = error

log4j2.appender.console.type = Console
log4j2.appender.console.name = LogToConsole
log4j2.appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

#log4j2.appender.file.type = File
#log4j2.appender.file.name = LogToFile
#log4j2.appender.file.fileName=logs/app.log
#log4j2.appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
#log4j2.appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

# Rotate log file
log4j2.appender.rolling.type = RollingRandomAccessFile 
log4j2.appender.rolling.name = LogToRollingRandomAccessFile
log4j2.appender.rolling.fileName = ${server.home}/logs/server.log
log4j2.appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
log4j2.appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.max = 10

# Log to console and rolling file
#logger.app.type = AsyncLogger
log4j2.logger.app.name = com.ssl.server
log4j2.logger.app.level = info
log4j2.logger.app.additivity = false
log4j2.logger.app.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingRandomAccessFile
log4j2.logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref = LogToConsole

log4j2.rootLogger.level = info
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LogToConsole
```

I have below dependancies in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am initializing the logger as below

```
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(SSLServer.class.getName());
```

When I start the standalone Java application using the `main()` am getting below error and `server.log` file is not created, I did some research regarding the below error and most of the articles were referring to `log4j2.xml` configuration and none of the config changes worked in my `log4j2.properties`

```
log warn: org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger - No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
```

Comment: Could you try `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("conf/log4j2.properties").getFile()` ?

Comment: @Villat, Thanks for the response, as per the official `log4j` doc I see that by default it will look for `log4j-test.properties` if `log4j.configurationFile` is not provided, can you please check my `log4j2.properties` and see why its not creating the log file

Comment: Hey, the `log4j2.properties` file has priority over the `log4j2.xml` so, could you add your project structure to the post? Maybe a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Few things to look at:

- make sure you don't have any other log4j2 config files on your classpath. The list is not small and can trip up. See it [in the documentation here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration).
- get debug info out of **log4j2** by increasing status messages: `status = info` (`debug` or `trace` )
- remove `log4j2.` as the prefix from all your properties so that `log4j2.appender.console.type = Console` becomes `appender.console.type = Console`
- add file logging to your `rootlogger`:
   `rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToFile`

Answer (score 3):

I adapted your configuration to work. Please check this out:

```
# Print configuration errors only
status=error

# Console appender
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

# Rotate log file
appender.rolling.type=RollingRandomAccessFile
appender.rolling.name=LogToRollingRandomAccessFile
appender.rolling.fileName=${SERVER_HOME}/logs/server.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1KB                        <-- for testing only!
appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max=10

# Root logger
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref=LogToConsole
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=LogToRollingRandomAccessFile
```

Please make sure you have the **SERVER_HOME** variable in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are declaring a root logger in you log4j.properties file.

I see, at the bottom, where you are setting the "level" on the rootlogger but I don't see where you've established the rootLogger.

My log4j.properties file start out like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, FILE, CONSOLE


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %20t %25F:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two modifications in your properties configuration:

- Remove the prefix "log4j2."
- Remove the space after "appender.rolling.type =
  RollingRandomAccessFile "

Also check if your package name is correct:

- logger.app.name = com.ssl.server

```
status = error

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

#appender.file.type = File
#appender.file.name = LogToFile
#appender.file.fileName=logs/app.log
#appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
#appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

# Rotate log file
appender.rolling.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
appender.rolling.name = LogToRollingRandomAccessFile
appender.rolling.fileName = logs/server.log
appender.rolling.fileName = ${server.home}/logs/server.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 10

# Log to console and rolling file
#logger.app.type = AsyncLogger
logger.app.name = com.ssl.server
logger.app.level = info
logger.app.additivity = false
logger.app.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingRandomAccessFile
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref = LogToConsole

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LogToConsole
```